# Best way for new users with low reputation to clarify unclear question

Tags: discussion

I joined Super User today after being redirected here from SO. I saw a question that was unclear and thought I could answer it with a little clarification from the poster, but wasn't able to comment on the question because my reputation was too low.

I understand that new users shouldn't be allowed to comment on questions to prevent 'noise' from curious visitors, but shouldn't there be a way to use distinguish users who also have Stack Overflow accounts from **absolutely** new users? At the very least, questions that have been migrated from SO should allow comments from Super Users who have active SO accounts.

I'm saying this because I was **forced** to post answer with an ambiguous [question](https://superuser.com/questions/412491/running-macro-through-nppexec-notepad). Won't this affect answer quality? Someone please suggest a good way to avoid this problem in future.

Comment: Try some other questions (or site) in the mean time, it doesn't take much to get to 200 reputation. And looking at your reputation, you're already halfway. :)

Comment: Yup, I took nhinkle's advice and went crazy here! :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a mechanism for this in place; it just requires that you have a little bit more reputation on the site you came from. Any user that has 200 reputation on *any* Stack Exchange site will get an automatic 100 point bonus on any other Stack Exchange site, allowing you to vote and comment right away. As soon as you get to 200 anywhere else, you'll get those privileges over here!

Comment: Oops I guess I missed that on the FAQs. So I guess I just slog it away in SO and come back here with some more privileges!

Comment: Or go crazy here and you'll get more privileges there. Either way works!

Comment: @prrao: **Related:** http://superuser.com/privileges